# Converting CVS multi-project tree hierarchy to Git?

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, project, cvs

I am using [CVS](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/cvs) and I have this hierarchy:

```
/ROOT
    /JAVA
        /JavaProject1
        /JavaProject2
        .project
    /PHP
        /PHPProject1
        /PHPProject2
        .project
```

In [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) > [CVS Repository Exploring](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-32.htm), I can see this hierarchy and I can [Check Out](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-40a.htm) only the project that I want.

Also I can check out (import) `JAVA` and `PHP` folders (I created them as Eclipse General project for import) to Eclipse Package Explorer and can synchronize and commit all together.

When I want to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/), it only supports one project.

I don't want a **flat hierarchy** (near all `JAVA` and `PHP` project together), I want to use **tree hierarchy** and I want to **check out only the project that I want** as with CVS.

Is my CVS hierarchy possible in Git or what technique should I use?

Comment: Sub-modules might be what you are after, but I don't know enough about them to construct an answer: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Normally you would have separate git repository per project. Most probably this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing what you want to do locally with how you want
to arrange things remotely. All git commands access only the local
repository. The 'push' and 'fetch' commands appear to access a remote
repository, but in fact they effectively start each other on the remote
machine running against the local repository on that machine. So the
tasks you can do remotely are very limited. Specifically, copying "branch"
and "tag" references and the commit histories those references point at.

This means for the simple case there is ONLY the local repository,
it exists in the `.git` directory in the working directory.

You can arrange working directories, with their `.git` directories however
you wish on your local machine. Likewise, you can arrange the the remote
repositories in any way allowed by the remote hosting service. The
layouts do not have to match. If the remote is your own Linux server you
can make the layout just like your local. If the remote is (for example)
Github you're more limited.

You'll need to backup the `.git` directory to backup 
the repository; the rest of the working directory is probably not significant. You can use `git push` to do this backup, as long as you never use '--force'.

Git isn't really very keen on you having multiple working directories
for one repository.  It is possible, however, in the simple case they
will each have their own copy of the repository and you will need to
push/pull the updates individually either to a "central" repository
or more "randomly". None of these repositories have to be physically
"remote".

Git much prefers you to switch between branches in one working directory
and use `make install` style processes to send builds out.

It is also possible to have unrelated branches in one repository, but most people find this too confusing as you still only have one working directory.